# IndexError: list index out of range in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import subprocess
import sys

video_link, threads = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
subprocess.call([
   "youtube-dl",
    video_link,
   "--external-downloader",
   "aria2c",
   "--external-downloader-args",
   "-x"+threads
])
```

Whenever I run the code the following error pops up. Help me please

> _link, threads = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Try `print(sys.argv)` and see what it outputs.

Comment: How do you call your script? Are you providing the requested args?

Comment: You say "When I run the code". Can you edit the question and copy/paste the way you run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely missing the arguments.

When you run,

```
python myscript.py arg1 arg2
```

sys.argv is a list with 
myscript.py at sys.argv[0],arg1 at sys.argv[1], etc

So consider using if conditions or try-except to check if we have necessary arguments to unpack:

```
import subprocess
import sys

if len(sys.argv)>2:

    myscript.pyvideo_link, threads = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    subprocess.call([
   "youtube-dl",
    video_link,
   "--external-downloader",
   "aria2c",
   "--external-downloader-args",
   "-x"+threads
])

else:
    print('Missing Video link and thread arguments')
    #raise Error if desired
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your `sys.argv` has fewer than 3 items.

What does `sys.argv` store?

It stores the arguments passed to your script by the command line.

For instance. If you run `python myscript.py an_arg another_one` the values stored in `sys.argv` are going to be `['myscript.py', 'an_arg', 'another_one']`.

Please, take your time to check the docs on [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).